# Get OS from AD using powershell with shorter criteria

Tags: powershell, active-directory, operating-system

Is there a shorter way to write this powershell code?
I want to know if there is a better way to query multiple criteria and return the answer at the bottom.

```
$PC = Read-Host -Prompt 'Give me PC name'
$OSname = $null
$OS = $null

$OS = (get-adcomputer $PC -Properties operatingSystem).OperatingSystem

If ($OS -like "Windows 10*")
{
$OSname = "Win 10"
}
If ($OS -like "*Server 2022*")
{
$OSname = "Win 2022"
}
If ($OS -like "*Server 2019*")
{
$OSname = "Win 2019"
}
If ($OS -like "*Server 2016*")
{
$OSname = "Win 2016"
}
If ($OS -like "*Server 2012*")
{
$OSname = "Win 2012"
}
If ($OS -like "Windows 7*")
{
$OSname = "Win 7"
}
If ($OS -like "*Server 2008*")
{
$OSname = "Win 2008"
}
If ($OS -eq $null)
{
$OSname = "NO OS"
}
$Osname
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement:

```
$OS = "Microsoft Server 2022 NL"
$OSName = switch -wildcard ($OS) {
    "Windows 10*"   { "Win 10" }
    "*Server 2022*" { "Win 2022" }
    "*Server 2019*" { "Win 2019" }
    "*Server 2016*" { "Win 2016" }
    "*Server 2012*" { "Win 2012" }
    "Windows 7*"    { "Win 7" }
    "*Server 2008*" { "Win 2008" }
    ""              { "NO OS" }
    Default         { "Other" }
}
$OSName
```

```
Win 2022
```

Answer (score 3):

@iRon answer is correct and straight forward. Using a `switch` statement in place of multiple `if` statements is the best way to go.

I wanted to provide an alternative answer if you are looking to just shorten your code. This takes advantage of using [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) and `regex`

Example:

```
$PC = Read-Host -Prompt 'Give me PC name'

Get-ADComputer $PC -Properties OperatingSystem | Select @{L="OperatingSystem";E={
    if($_.OperatingSystem -match ('([Windows]).*(?:\d{1,})')){return $Matches[0] -replace "Windows", "Win" -replace "Server ", "" -replace "R2 ", ""}
    else{return "Other"}
}}
```

Comment: This is also a good answer,  However it does not return the server OS in the shortened format I want.  i.e  Win 2008, Win 2012, Win 2019 etc..

Comment: Good catch. I updated it to remove `"Server "`

Comment: It likes to put "R2" in there on some of them but this is good:   I changed it to:    `(Get-ADComputer $PC -Properties OperatingSystem | Select @{L="OperatingSystem";E={
    if($_.OperatingSystem -match ('([Windows]).*(?:\d{1,})')){return $Matches[0] -replace "Windows", "Win" -replace "Server ", ""} else{return "Other"}}}).OperatingSystem`

Comment: Fixed by adding:   -replace "R2", ""